# R predict not yielding correct length

Tags: r, glm, predict

I have a simple positive/negative test result as a function of a protein concentration, and I am trying to plot the logit regression curve. However, I am consistently getting a error that I cannot fix.

This is my data:

```
sp <- structure(list(Cry = c(32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 16, 16, 16, 8, 
8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.12, 0.12, 0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Positive = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

This is my glm:

```
test.glm <- glm(Positive ~ Cry, family = binomial, data = sp)
summary(test.glm)
```

I am trying to make predicted values to plot

```
x_test <- seq(0,32, 0.01)
y_test <- predict(test.glm, newdata =  list(x_test) ,type = "response")
```

So, when I try to plot it:

```
plot(sp$Positive ~ log(Cry))
lines(x_test, y_test)
```

I get this error:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

because

```
length(x_test)
3201
length(y_test)
36
```

The length of y_test ends up being 36 instead of the same length as x_test

Why is my predict function ignoring the length of my newdata and only predicting as many values as I have in my original dataframe?

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: Thanks! It is my first post. I figures it wasn`t optimal but I could not figure out how to attach a data.frama directly.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you were looking for?

```
test.glm <- glm(Positive ~ Cry, family = binomial, data = sp)
x_test <- seq(0,32,0.01)
y_text <- predict(test.glm,newdata = data.frame(Cry = x_test),type="response")
plot(sp, Positive ~ log(Cry))
lines(x_test,y_test)
```

[image]

**Data**

```
sp <- structure(list(Cry = c(32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 16, 16, 16, 8, 
8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.12, 0.12, 0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Positive = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for the reply. Sorry I wasn`t able to attach the dataframe is a better way.

I made the same change you made (from list to data.frame),, except I assigned the predict to y_test (which I think you forgot). and it still does not work.

If it works in your R but not mine, I suppose it means it is some bug or incompatibility in my machine?

Comment: Nice catch, I did forget the assignment. I had to change the colname of the `sp` data.frame `Cry1Ab` to `Cry` as well. Could that be it?

Comment: Nope. Also worth mentioning, I got this warning when running your version of y_test:

Warning message:
'newdata' had 3201 rows but variables found have 36 rows

I suppose that is part of the problem?

Comment: Strange, I get no warning. From `sessionInfo()` I am using `R version 3.6.3.`

Comment: I get this:
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)
. I just tried updating RStudio and R just in case, and It still does not work.

Comment: I found the problem! It turns out the code will not work if you write the glm as glm(sp$Cry ~ sp$Positive, family = binomial). You have to explicitly name the variables, like in the new code. I had not rerun the glm after the code was adjusted.
Thanks for the help!